# preventDefault and use link as toggle

Tags: jquery, toggle

First, I'm at the very beginning of learning jQuery.

I'm trying to preventDefault on a blog title link, and rather use it as a toggle for the blog content that is below it.  Because all blog entries use the same class I need to use .next to only select the next class.  I would love any suggestions for how to get this code to work.  Thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.u-url').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});

$('.u-url').click(function(){
 $(this).next('.entry-content').toggle();
});
</script>
```

The Markup is complicated...but I didn't create it.  It's part of a Squarespace site.  I've taken out div's that don't apply (like date of post which is not hidden or part of the problem)

```
<h1 id="yui_3_17_2_1_1406693227055_2849" class="entry-title p-name" data-content-field="title">
    <a id="yui_3_17_2_1_1406693227055_2848" class="u-url" rel="bookmark" href="url-here"></a>
</h1>
<div class="entry-content"></div>
```

I have "entry-content" hidden with CSS and trying to have it toggle when clicking the title of the blog post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the `.closest()` to get the parent matched with the supplied selector and then grab the next element to it with the class `.entry-content`, then `toggle` it.

```
$('.u-url').click(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   $(this).closest(':header').next('.entry-content').toggle();
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MEz26/2/)

Your code is not working because `.entry-content` is not the immediate sibling to the current element i.e] `$(this)`

---

**Edit:**

```
$('.u-url').click(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   $(this).closest('header.entry-header').next('.entry-content').toggle();
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MEz26/3/)

Comment: I see it works in the demo, but it's not working on the site.

Comment: @twoarmtom Can you link me to your live site..?

Comment: [link](https://thecsrt.squarespace.com/announcements2/), I'm currently building this demo site, so it's not "active".  Click "Visitor" and type the code it gives you.

Comment: @twoarmtom Try the updated coded, i just checked down your site. :)